# Laravel Echo and Vue.js cannot listen to Whisper

Tags: laravel, pusher, laravel-echo

I am trying to create a listener for 'typing' event using Laravel Echo and Pusher, and laravel websockets.
I have managed to send the whisper event to pusher, which is sent successfully and my pusher console displays the received event as below

```
myAppId: connection id 60612368.93289095 received message: {"event":"client-typing","data":52,"channel":"private-message.52.1"}.
```

However, on the receiving end, I am trying to display the 'user is typing' on my browser, but .listenForWhisper receives nothing. I have been trying to research on the same issue but I cannot figure out why I am not receiving it on my browser.

My code is as below:

```
Echo.private(`message.${fromId}.${toId}`)
    .whisper('typing', this.auth.id)


Echo.private(`message.${fromId}.${toId}`)
    .listenForWhisper('typing', (response) => {
        console.log("typing");
        console.log(response);
    })
```

All the parameters are passed correctly to the functions, but for some reason I cannot listen to the whisper event. I have also enabled enable_client_messages in my websockets config. It is as below:

```
'apps' => [
    [
        'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),
        'capacity' => null,
        'enable_client_messages' => true,
        'enable_statistics' => true,
    ],
],
```

If someone can kindly guide me how to go about this issue, it would be great.

Comment: I believe whisper-events are only sent to other users in the same channel. Do you have 2 users log in to check if it works or you have the same page opened by the same user?

Comment: Yes I have tried with 3 users on the same channel, but I still do not get any response from it. I am supposing its an issue with my websocket configurations. Not sure though.

Comment: Can you verify that your channels work besides your whisper? Like does it work to send events via a regular channel or private channel from server to client?

Comment: Yes I can send and receive chat messages on the channels. I am also using the channels to receive notifications, which works well. However for the whisper, I still cannot figure it out

Comment: Did you setup authentication for the channel in channels.php?

Comment: @RobBiermann Yes I have followed and tried several tutorials for the authentication channels. I have still failed to listen to the whispers. It is very weird in my instance as all other events are being transmitted on the channel apart from the whisper

Comment: this is an old question, but I have feeling that the issue was with `${fromId}.${toId}` because on the other side this would be in reverse. I fixed this by using a following scheme: `${smallerId}.${biggerId}`  to make sure the room/channel name will always match for both parties